# Remote connections in windows 7

Tags: windows, remote

I need help.

In Windows 7

I remotely taking one server(A) using mstsc.again I take remote to different server(B).Now I taking two remotes. If I want to transfer file from sever A To Server B.I just want to know how the process runs.....

thanks

Comment: If you want to transfer a file from Server A to Server B you would have to make a connection to Server A from Server B or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access both of these servers from your main computer, and get authenticated, then you can do this in file explorer without having to remote into either computer, per se.

Type in the ip address in file explorer in the address bar with c$ at the end to get the C:\ of the server you're trying to access. For example, \\192.168.1.2\c$ will try to access the C:\ of the server with the address 192.168.1.2. Open two file explorers and do one server in one file explorer, and the other server in the other file explorer, and you then have file transferring abilities without using mstsc!

Here is an image to explain what I mean further:
[image]